# Angular Material Datepicker - Translate Month Label (inside of the year picker button)

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my project I need to translate datepicker to Ukrainian locale. Everything works fine exept of the month label. It remains with en locale. How can I translate label inside of the top left button (where you pick the year)?

```
export class CustomDateAdapter extends MomentDateAdapter {
  public override getDayOfWeekNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow') {
    return ['Нд', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'];
  }
  public override getMonthNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow') {
    return [
      'Січ',
      'Лют',
      'Бер',
      'Квіт',
      'Трав',
      'Черв',
      'Лип',
      'Серп',
      'Вер',
      'Жовт',
      'Лист',
      'Груд',
    ];
  }

  public override getFirstDayOfWeek() {
    return 1;
  }
}

export const MATERIAL_DATEPICKER_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MM YYYY',
  },
};


For now only solution I have is to remove MMM from monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the missing parts is overriding the `getDateNames` function, which in the `MomentDateAdapter` is resolved using the provided locale. And since you didn't provide locale, it falls back to the default, which IIRC is en-US.

That being said, why not simply provide the Ukrainian locale and let moment use it's standard naming? Like this:

```
{provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'uk'},
```

You can provide it either on the module level or component level, and it will apply the locale for dates. Working stackblitz (using your date formats) [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgnngt).

Comment: I tried this. Material adds russian locale for ua

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? In the stackblitz that I've linked I can definitely see non-russian month names, and by the looks of it those seems to be Ukrainian (sorry, I'm far from being language specialist). Are you saying those are incorrect?
Perhaps you're using older version of moment.js and should update your dependencies?

Comment: Thank you! I missed the MomentDateAdapter part!